# I want to change MRTK3 Ray Interactor Input Action Change in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk

I am learning MRTK3 in Unity, and it is very similar to XRI.

I bind Select(Input Action) with gripPressed because I am using it in GrabInteractor.

but I realize Ray Interactor is working with Select(Input Action), and I delete triggerPressed in Select(Input Action). I can't RayInteract with object in trigger button. but RayInteract works in grip button. And I want to RayInteract with trigger button.

In Short, I bind UIPress(Input Action) with triggerPressed. but I don't know how can I change Input Action in RayInteract...

I already know how to change in XRI. but I think MRTK3 little bit different.

[image]

Comment: You can stop actually ^^ [Microsoft abandoned MRTK etc](https://www.bigtechwire.com/2023/01/20/microsoft-fires-entire-mixed-reality-toolkit-mrtk-development-team/?amp=1)

Comment: @derHugo OMG...MS abandoned MRTK?... I can understand because MRTK is totally lots of bug shit in unity... thx though. bless you.